Auth0 - Angular 17 - Bearer token not added using Auth0 interceptor
I have found that making an API call made during an ngOnInit on a page which is protected by the Auth0 Route Guard has the Bearer token added correctly. As Expected.
However the same method call triggered from a page which is not behind the Auth0 Guard does not have the bearer token added.
I have tried adding a backup interceptor for this call only (in case it is the Route Guard issue) but it is stripped off!
My interceptor is:
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandlerFn,
  HttpInterceptorFn,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
import { Observable, switchMap } from 'rxjs';

export const paymentInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (
  req: HttpRequest<any>,
  next: HttpHandlerFn
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);

  return authService.getAccessTokenSilently().pipe(
    switchMap((token) => {
      const newRequest = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
      return next(newRequest);
    })
  );
};

I have logged the newRequest and it does contain the new Header entry however the network tab does not show it anymore.
Is my guess correct? Thoughts?
The app.config.ts simply contains:
 export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideAuth0({ ...env.auth0 }),
    provideHttpClient(
      withInterceptors([authHttpInterceptorFn, paymentInterceptor])
    ),
  ],
};


